# How can we do password confirmation in angular front-end?

Tags: angular

How can we do password confirmation in angular front-end?
I see some angular functions in html like this:

```
    <form #signUpForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="signUpForm.valid && onSubmit(signUpForm)">

  <input type="text" #username="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userService.selectedUser.username" name="username" placeholder="Full Name"
  required  [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox' :signUpForm.submitted && !username.valid }">
  <div *ngIf="signUpForm.submitted && !username.valid">
    <label class="validation-message">This field is required.</label>
  </div>

  <input type="password" #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userService.selectedUser.password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
  minlength="4" required [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox' :signUpForm.submitted && !password.valid }">
  <div *ngIf="signUpForm.submitted && password.errors">
    <label *ngIf="password.errors.required" class="validation-message">This field is required.</label>
    <label *ngIf="password.errors.minlength" class="validation-message">Enter atleast 4 characters.</label>
  </div>

  <input type="password" #confirmPassword="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userService.selectedUser.confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="confirmPassword"
  required [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox' :signUpForm.submitted && !confirmPassword.valid }">
  <div *ngIf="signUpForm.submitted && confirmPassword.errors">
    <label *ngIf="confirmPassword.errors.required" class="validation-message">This field is required.</label>
    <label *ngIf="???" class="validation-message">password not match</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  
</form>
```

So I'm expecting that there is also a function like that for password confirmation to verify if your confirm password is true or false

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use rxwebvalidator, which has built in compare function

npm i @rxweb/reactive-form-validators

here's an working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxweb-reactive-form-validator-angular-4zdeux

Alternatively you can write your own code to test if password and confirm password are the same

```html
   <form #signUpForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="signUpForm.valid && onSubmit(signUpForm)">

  <input type="text" #username="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userService.selectedUser.username" name="username" placeholder="Full Name"
  required  [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox' :signUpForm.submitted && !username.valid }">
  <div *ngIf="signUpForm.submitted && !username.valid">
    <label class="validation-message">This field is required.</label>
  </div>

  <input type="password" #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userService.selectedUser.password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
  minlength="4" required [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox' :signUpForm.submitted && !password.valid }">
  <div *ngIf="signUpForm.submitted && password.errors">
    <label *ngIf="password.errors.required" class="validation-message">This field is required.</label>
    <label *ngIf="password.errors.minlength" class="validation-message">Enter atleast 4 characters.</label>
  </div>
  
  <input type="password" #confirmPassword="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userService.selectedUser.confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Password"
  minlength="4" required [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox' :signUpForm.submitted && !password.valid }">
  <div *ngIf="signUpForm.submitted">
    <label *ngIf="userService.selectedUser.password != userService.selectedUser.confirmPassword" class="validation-message">Enter atleast 4 characters.</label>
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  
</form>
```

Comment: However, this will not stop form submission, in onSubmit method, you will have to check again if they matched. I'd recommend @rxweb/reactive-form-validators